# Spring 2.6.3: Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute

Tags: spring, pom.xml, mysql-connector, application.properties

I have created a new Spring Starter Project and I specified in `application.properties` the db settings:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useUnicode=yes&character_set_server=utf8mb4
spring.datasource.username=.....
spring.datasource.password=.....
```

in `pom.xml` I have the mysql dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

I have also done `maven -> Update`....

When starting the project the console says:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

I don´t understand..i just provided what he needs...the datasource.url...

When I change the `spring version to 2.3.0.RELEASE`...it works. But why not with the `newer one 2.6.3`?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Spring .properties file uses kebab-case for its key values.

You have

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

when it should be

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: cool tip, but that doesn´t resolve the problem. still same error, wenn I have Spring version 2.6.3